# Is mysql’s lag function non-deterministic without an ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql

I’ve been working on a query using the lag function. My initial query appeared to be returning the correct data, even though I left out the ORDER BY in the OVER clause. I was partitioning over several columns.

Then I added a WHERE clause and was surprised to find that the result set returned contained rows which were not in the unfiltered query.

My question is, is there a use case for using lag without an ORDER BY in the OVER clause? I also read in the documentation that lag does not even require an OVER clause, but it seems to me, that without the OVER and the ORDER BY lag would return random values from the column. Am I missing something?

It seems like OVER and ORDER BY in the OVER clause should be an error.

Comment: Yes, anything that depends on ordering is unpredictable if you don't use `ORDER BY`. But it doesn't generate an error, just like using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`.

Comment: It will just use the order that the data happens to be in, at that point in the execution plan. That may be table order, index order, an order due to another window function, etc. Which is the worst kind of nondeterministic result; one that usually doesn't vary, but subtle changes to data, server load, indexing, view definitions, etc, can spontaneously cause it to vary. What valid use cases are there? I can't think of any. But, the result WILL always be valid for that given (though hidden) ordering, and WILL be calculated AFTER the WHERE clause had been applied.

Comment: `Then I added a WHERE clause and was surprised to find that the result set returned contained rows which were not in the unfiltered query.` Do you have a reproducible example? Because that's not how window functions work. Though the ordering used will be Arbitrary (just a side effect of the table structure, other parts of the query, etc), a window function should NEVER return a value from a row filtered out by the WHERE clause (the only nondeterministic aspect of this should be the arbitrary ordering of the input rows).

Comment: Note that even if you specify order by, if it does not fully differentiate you can and will get different results from lag (e.g. order by date, but multiple rows for a partition+date)

Comment: @MatBailie - It did not return a value filtered out by the WHERE clause, it returned a different set of rows (filtered correctly). ie lag returned a different value, and that value was used to join another table.

Comment: Are there any tools that you can use that will "lint" your SQL, and give warnings for things like this. i.e.
  Window function calls without order by
  Using group operators without a group by
  Using a group by that doesn't span all of the non-grouped columns?